# Should we burninate [extracting]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, tags, burnination

In its current definition, [extracting](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extracting) has partly the same definition as [background-removal](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/background-removal) and part 'accessing defined data from larger datasets'. I'd like to either kill the entire tag or have it just mean the second thing.

update: It is done. I created a new [data-extraction](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-extraction) for the questions that need it.

Comment: Nuke from orbit, its the only way to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "or" doesn't make any sense to me. Theres absolutely no reason at all to have a tag with two completely unrelated meanings.

There are <del>no</del> not many questions using the tag for the second "data-extraction" meaning (maybe [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/42668/52050), which looks off-topic and confusing) and I'm not sure that has all that much to do with graphic design anyway. There are a few questions that are talking about using CC's "Extract Assets" feature, which I don't think fits in either description.

So, *if* we're going to do anything with it: remove the "or..." from the description and make it a synonym of [background-removal](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/background-removal) and retag existing questions. Or better yet...

Kill it.

Comment: I disagree on the 'there are no questions' part. There are multiple questions using 'extracting' as a tag for, say, getting a measurement from a curve already drawn or a font from a .pdf.

Comment: Well, I can only find 2 but yeh I guess so. "accessing defined data from larger datasets" is a bit ambiguous, I wouldn't fit measurements in to that definition but that's just arguing semantics.

Comment: That's weird. I found at least 5... Let me search again.

Comment: I wasn't looking that thoroughly so I probably just missed them

Comment: I'd vote to convert 'extraction' to 'background-removal'; and add 'data-extraction' to all the (5?) questions we are stumbling over now.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable course of action